# Why is else if block ignored when I add else block?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why this happens? I'm doing exercise on FreeCodeCamp (Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The returned value should be a number.)
I know there are better ways to do this but I'm interested in this problem.
This is my code:

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
let pos = 0;
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(arr);

for(let arrs in arr) {

  if (num == arr[+arrs]) {
    return pos = +arrs;
  }

  else if (num < arr[+arrs]) {
    pos = ((+arrs));
    return pos;
  }

  else {
    return "why"
  }

}

return 0;

}

console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 20, 10], 19));
console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15));
```

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: Because `return` exits from the function. If you change it to `console.log('why')`, the correct value will still be obtained.

Comment: You never loop more than once. You return in all three branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are returning `"why"` at the start of the loop, so basically 19 would be compared to 2, and when it finds that `19 === 2` is false and `19 < 2` is false, it returns `"why"` and gets out of the function without looping through the elements, same goes for the second array.

Try to use an array in which all the values are bigger than `num` and you will see that it gives you 0.

the solution would be to erase the third else altogether.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `if-else-if` flow. The `if-else-if` work procedure is like below:

1. `if` is false, check next `else if` condition
2. if next `else if` condition is also false, will check the next `else if` condition if ther is any.
3. if there is no more `else if` condition, it will find `else` condition and work on that, if not found, will work on rest of statements

So, in your case, if first `if` is true, the look works only once, if that is false, then check next `else if` and if it is true, the loop ends, otherwise directly goes to `else` condition and returns from here running the loop only once. That's why it runs only once.